# Group structure on the elliptic curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions

I'm reading Jürgen Jost's book; Compact Riemann Surface. 
In the chapter of elliptical curves I find the following theorem:

"Theorem 5.10.3 In the group structure on the elliptic curve $\Sigma$ given by $y^{2}=4x^{3}-g_{2}x -g_{3}$, we will have $p_{1}+p_{2}+p_{3}=0$ if and only if $p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}$ lie on line in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$."

I read the demonstration, but I do not understand ... I wonder if I can find it in another reference, another book about this result.

thank you

Comment: If you don't understand the group law of an elliptic curve then I think you need to read it somewhere. The book in the answer below is a good start, and there're the excellent books by Silverman or Koblitz for example. In short, $\;P+Q=0\;$ iff one is the reflexion thru the $\;x\,-$ axis of the other one. Seeing the definition of the sum, this happens in your case iff $\;P_3\;$ is that reflexion of $\;P_1+P_2\;$ , iff the three points are collinear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of books about elliptic curves. One cheap one is Milne's book "Elliptic curves".

I'll try to explain the group structure in more than one sentence:

So a group structure on $\Sigma$ means that we have a rule for adding two points and getting a third point. Furthermore, there is an identity element, the group operation is commutative and associative.

The rule is this: Let $P,Q \in \Sigma$. Then we define $P+Q$ to be the following point: let $L_{PQ}$ be the line between $P$ and $Q$. Since $\Sigma$ is a curve a degree $3$, this line intersect $\Sigma$ in a third point $R'$. Then we define $P+Q$ to be the reflection of $R'$ about the $x$ axis.

Note that this definition makes commutativity clear: $L_{PQ}=L_{QP}$. Associativity is much harder to prove.

The identity element is the "point at infinity", it has homogeneous coordinates $(0:0:1)$. Think of it as a point "infinitely high above the finite plane". Then $L_{P0}$ (letting 0 denote the point at infinity) is just a vertical line. Then (if you draw an example), you'll see that $P+0=P$.

Comment: Milne's book is available for free on his website: http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ectext5.pdf.

Comment: I don't like describing this as reflecting in the $x$-axis, since this is in projective space. You should really repeat what you already did once, now with the given point and the point at infinity.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft For any actual computation where a plane is avalable to sketch the elliptic curve, it is simply reflection thru the $\;x\,-$ axis. Someone wanting something more accurate will surely study this more in deep and will observe the little fine points.

Comment: In agreement with @TobiasKildetoft, I remark that in characteristic $2$, it’s not reflection in the $x$-axis that one uses.

Answer (score 2):

Take the book: "Algebraic Curves" by Fulton, pag 63 and exercise 5.41 (case m = 1).